# Arrays and addition

Tags: ios, objective-c

What I want to have happen:
Items in array show up in a label.  Each item in the array will have it's own label.
I eventually want to add more items.

And make it so that index 0 of thisArray can be added to index 0 of that array; display in a label;
object at index 1 in thisArray can be added to object at index 1 in thatArray and then the result can be displayed in a separate label, 
and so on
To appear on a button click.

I'm having a lot of trouble implementing this and I feel like it is a lot simpler than I am making it. Any insight would be appreicated!!

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


self.steakArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"800", @"50", nil];

//NSString *name;
NSString *calories = [_steakArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fat = [_steakArray objectAtIndex:1];



}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//this doesn't work, this is what I want to have happen though.
//click button, show this in label.
- (IBAction)steak:(id)sender {

self.infoLabel.text = calories, fat;

}
@end
```

Comment: Why are your calories counts being kept as strings instead of numbers?

Comment: because I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: When you say "added to" do you really mean numerical addition or do you mean appended, like strings?

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a dictionary, so you don't have the think about what index hold the correct index when you could use a string to represent each value.

Comment: numerical.  the values are numbers. I want them to be able to literally be added together.

Comment: How would I go about doing this with a dictionary then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at this documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html

You can use String with Format:

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A string: %@, a float: %1.2f",

                                               @"string", 31415.9265];

// string1 is "A string: string, a float: 31415.93"



NSNumber *number = @1234;

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"date": [NSDate date]};

NSString *baseString = @"Base string.";

NSString *string2 = [baseString stringByAppendingFormat:

        @" A number: %@, a dictionary: %@", number, dictionary];

// string2 is "Base string. A number: 1234, a dictionary: {date = 2005-10-17 09:02:01 -0700; }"
```

Comment: This answer would probably help the OP more if it was written using their methods and variables from the question's code.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are getting calories in string, you can use the following code to add and display in the label

```
NSString *calories1 = [_steakArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *calories2 = [_steakArray2 objectAtIndex:0];

int sum = [calories1 intValue] + [calories2 intValue];

self.infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sum];
```